# fstab - windows диски монтируются в режиме read only

Tags: linux, администрирование

До недавнего времени работал на Ubuntu. По некоторым причинам перешёл на Fedora.

Во время загрузки ОС у меня монтируются (посредством  *fstab*) два диска от винды и один - nas4free. На Ubuntu всё прекрасно работало. Однако, на Fedora все эти диски монтируются только на чтение.

Содержимое файла *fstab*:

```
UUID=b1b0ef8c-b898-450d-9ab6-abfa03eeaa8e /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
UUID=4856d5f6-b3cd-4e26-934d-f169e1fb8e69 /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=04dfcc7b-f922-43db-94d6-4b6263535f6d /opt                    ext4    defaults        1 2

# Windows
/dev/sda2 /mnt/disk_c ntfs-3g rw,user,users,gid=users,fmask=113,dmask=002,locale=ru_RU.UTF-8 0 0
/dev/sda3 /mnt/disk_d ntfs-3g rw,user,users,gid=users,fmask=113,dmask=002,locale=ru_RU.UTF-8 0 0

# nas4free
//192.168.0.168/common1  /mnt/nas4free  cifs rw,auto,gid=users,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/etc/winpassword 0 0
bash-5.0$
```

Если смотреть выдачу команды *mount*, то там эти диски показаны, как смонтированные r/w:

```
$ mount
. . . 
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/disk_c type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,user)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/disk_d type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,user)
//192.168.0.168/common1 on /mnt/nas4free type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=2.1,cache=strict,username=lary,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=100,forcegid,addr=192.168.0.168,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

Фактически, это - старый файл... Но не работает!
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В логах ядра должна быть написана причина

Comment: Что  искать в логах?! В dmesg со словом "error" нет вообще ничего, а со словом "mount"  - только информация об успешном монтировани люниксовых дисков...

Comment: Если в mount написано rw, то почему вы тогда решили, что примонтировалось только на чтение?

Comment: @andreymal *почему вы тогда решили* - да тому, что когда я пытаюсь что-то **записать** на любой из этих дисков, то мне выдаётся сообщение "Permission denied (13)"

Comment: Ну так написано же, что у вас доступа нет. Доступ на запись есть только у root и у группы users, это чётко прописано в вашем fstab. Вы состоите в группе users?

Comment: Хотя судя по выводу команды mount, у вас группы users вообще не существует, следовательно, доступ на запись есть только у пользователя root.

Comment: @andreymal "Вы состоите в группе users?" - В какой группе? На сервере? На локальной машине? На Windows ? На сервере ничего не менялось, а в локалке - я просто переусталовил Linux...

Comment: Где нет доступа, там и нужно состоять. Это вам виднее, где вы монтируете и где у вас нет доступа

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое - проблема частично решилась. Я вспомнил, что в Ubuntu все пользователи автоматом включались в группу users. Проверил себя - нет меня там. Добавил. Теперь на Windows писать могу. К огромному сожалению, доступ на nas4free так и не появился :-(

Answer (score 0):

Для доступа к шаре на nas4free надо было добавить параметры *dir_mode=0777, file_mode=0777*. Теперь строка монтирования в файле   *fstab* выглядит следующим образом:

```
//192.168.0.168/common1  /mnt/nas4free  cifs rw,vers=1.0,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/etc/winpassword,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0
bash-5.0$
```

Теперь - читаю, пишу и создаю директории.